# Spring integration MQTT publish & subscribe to multiple topics

Tags: spring, spring-integration, publish-subscribe, mqtt

I am trying to build an application which subscribes to multiple mqtt topics, get the information, process it and form xmls and upon processing trigger an event so that these can be sent to some cloud server and the successful response from there to be sent back to the mqtt channel.

```
<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="mqttAdapter" client-id="${clientId}" url="${brokerUrl}" topics="${topics}"
    channel="startCase" auto-startup="true" />

<int:channel id="startCase" />

<int:service-activator id="startCaseService"
        input-channel="startCase" ref="msgPollingService" method="pollMessages" />

    <bean id="mqttTaskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="msgPollingService" class="com.xxxx.xxx.mqttclient.mqtt.MsgPollingService">
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="mqttTaskExecutor" />
        <property name="vendorId" value="${vendorId}" />
    </bean>
```

My question is how do I publish this to multiple channels, i.e. if I have an option to publish X message to Y topic. At present I have the below:

```
<int:channel id="outbound" />

<int-mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="mqtt-publish" client-id="kj" client-factory="clientFactory"
    auto-startup="true" url="${brokerUrl}" default-qos="0"
    default-retained="true" default-topic="${responseTopic}" channel="outbound" />

    <bean id="eventListner" class="com.xxxx.xxxx.mqttclient.event.EventListener">
        <property name="sccUrl" value="${url}" />
        <property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplate" />
        <property name="channel" ref="outbound" />
    </bean>
```

I can publish this like:

```
channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("customResponse").build());
```

Can I do something like:

```
channel.send(Message<?>, topic)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration looks good. However the `MessageChannel` is an abstraction for loosely-coupling and gets deal only with `Message`.

So, you request a-la `channel.send(Message<?>, topic)` isn't correct for Messaging concepts.

However we have a trick for you. From `AbstractMqttMessageHandler`:

```
String topic = (String) message.getHeaders().get(MqttHeaders.TOPIC);
.....
this.publish(topic == null ? this.defaultTopic : topic, mqttMessage, message);
```

So, what you need from your code is this:

```
channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("customResponse").setHeader(MqttHeaders.TOPIC, topic).build());
```

In other words you should send a `Message` with `mqtt_topic` header to achieve a dynamic publication from `<int-mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

From other side we don't recommend to use `MessageChannel`s directly from the application. The `<gateway>` with service interface is for such a case for end-application. Where that `topic` can be one of service method argument marked as `@Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC)`

Comment: Thanks, yes, gateway is what I'll implements as it seems more appropriate. Also, I may sound naive as I have just started implementing messaging systems, am I correct in defining separate channels for inbound and outbound?

Comment: Yes, that's true. If you aren't going to shift messages from one topic and send them to another you definitely need several channels.