# Spring Mqtt - Publish messages to multiple topics programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt, paho

How can I publish messages with different topics programmatically?

```
<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter id="mqttOut" 
    auto-startup="true" 
    client-id="foo"
    url="tcp://localhost:1883"
    client-factory="clientFactory"
    default-qos="0"
    default-retained="false"
    default-topic="bar"
    async="true"
    async-events="true" />
```

I tried [Spring integration MQTT publish & subscribe to multiple topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313985/spring-integration-mqtt-publish-subscribe-to-multiple-topics), but were not able to configure.

Also tried with `MqttPahoMessageHandlerAdapter` which has a `publish()` but `protected`.

Going with `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient` and `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback` is very easy. But I would like to stick with spring all the way.

Appreciate if somebody can points me to a correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `<publish-subscribe-channel id="toMqtt" />`; set it as the `channel` attribute on each outbound channel adapter; the message will be sent to each adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working. Also I tried with a `<channel id="myPublisher"/>` and a `<bridge input-channel="myPublisher" output-channel="IdOfMqttOutBoundAdapter"/>`. This worked too. But I had to remove `async-events="true"` from the `<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter id="IdOfMqttOutBoundAdapter" />`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Spring Integration anyway! Having a lot of EIP components implementation and Spring power on board (injection, SpEL etc,), plus switching on a bit of imagination, we can reach any end-application requirements even without any Java code.

So, `<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter>` allows determine `topic` at runtime. Instead of `default-topic` you should supply `MqttHeaders.TOPIC` `MessageHeader`.

So, if you have a requirement to send the same message to several topics, you just build a copy of that message for each topic. The `<splitter>` can help us:

```
<int:splitter input-channel="enricheMessage" output-channel="sendMessage" apply-sequence="false">
    <int-groovy:script>
        ['topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3'].collect {
            org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
                    .copyHeaders(headers)
                    .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.mqtt.support.MqttHeaders.TOPIC, it)
                    .build()
        }
    </int-groovy:script>
</int:splitter>
```

`sendMessage` can be `ExecutorChannel` to achieve the parallel publishing.

**UPDATE**

You can achieve the same iteration and message enrichment logic with similar Java code using `ref` and `method` on `<splitter>`.
Of course, we can do that even with SpEL , but it will look a bit complex with `Collection Projection`.

Comment: My topics get generated dynamically at run-time as per my scenario. I have 0 knowledge of groovy :(. I'm trying to achieve is, a server (a thread) should be able to send messages to dynamic topics when it requires. For example, I want to publish set of messages at 23:59 midnight to topic 'a', 'b' and 'c'. I next day, these topics may get changed.

Comment: So, you can do that by some Java code. And use `ref` and `method` on the `<splitter>`. And do exactly the same what I shown with Groovy code: iterate over your dynamic topics and return the `List<Message<?>>` with appropriate `MqttHeaders.TOPIC` header for each of them. Unfortunately `<publish-subscribe-channel>` (Gary's sample) won't help you...

Comment: Can you explain why did you choose `<splitter>`? Does `<splitter>` has any extra feature than `<publish-subscribe-channel>`? In the spring docs **The Splitter is a component whose role is to partition a message in several parts, and send the resulting messages to be processed independently.**. In this case I don't have any message to partition. But I have several messages to send.

Comment: With `<publish-subscribe-channel>` you must have the fixed subscribers with predefined `topics`. With `<splitter>` you will have several messages and send all of them to the same adapter with their own `topic`. Right, it looks a bit scary to split it that way, but there is no choice to distribute the same message for several runtime topics.

Comment: But I'm able to send them right now with `<publish-subscribe-channel>`. If you can check just now on http://mqttdashboard.com/dashboard, you can see multiple topics in  this `publish_subscribe_channel/<num1>/<num2>` format. Im just looping `<num2>` ftom 200 to 230. '<num1>` is like a random number.

Comment: Same `<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter>` as in the question + adding the `channel`. So now it is `<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter id="mqttOut" ... channel="toMqtt"/>` with `<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="toMqtt" />` as Gary mentioned. Nothing more in the config. In a Thread I have this `@Autowired(required=true) private MessageChannel toMqtt;`. In that Thread I loop `toMqtt.send(message);` where each looping `message` has its own `MqttHeaders.TOPIC`.

Comment: Well, you exactly did the same iteration which I pointed in my answer. What is the gain of ` <publish-subscribe-channel>` here? You have the same `<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter>` and only one. Gary mentioned it because he suggested to have several `<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter>`s for each topic.

Comment: Understood just now what you were trying to say. Actually I do not need `<publish-subscribe-channel>`. So If I start again, I do not need `<publish-subscribe-channel>` or `<splitter>`. It works with just `<mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter>`. But you pointed out parallel publishing. I'm interested in this phrase **sendMessage can be ExecutorChannel to achieve the parallel publishing** in your answer. I may have 10000 subscribers and each of them may subscribe to a separate topic. Is there any advantage of having a `<splitter>` because of this scale (number of subscribers and number of topics)?

Comment: Ideally, it would be better do not use Messaging API from your code (e.g. `messageChannel.send()`). That's because `<splitter>` helps you to hide your API and just rely on the standard component behavior.